# Can GPT-3 write an entire program if provided with detailed UML and ER Diagrams?

Tags: open-ai, deepmind

We already have tools like Denigma.app & Figstack.com (AI-powered code explanation in English), Codesee.io (Codebase and dependency mapping).
There's also a tool called [Enzyme.so](https://enzyme.so/) which converts English instructions to code.

All of us know about the capabilities of Github Copilot, OpenAI's [Codex](https://openai.com/blog/openai-codex/) and recently Deepmind's [AlphaCode](https://www.deepmind.com/blog/article/Competitive-programming-with-AlphaCode).

Taking all these advances into consideration, is there a possibility that GPT-3 or any sufficiently advanced engine can generate an entire codebase or program out of thoroughly detailed UML and ERD documents?
Have there been any advances in this direction already?

Comment: UML created strictly enough can drive non-AI code generators such as Rational Rose - https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Rational-Rose - that's not really an AI system though. I doubt GPT-3 or derived tools could do it, as they are typically not coherent enough to tackle large systems. I don't know enough about the topic to answer solidy, but thought the RR link might be helpful to you or anyone thinking of answering